# Chrome Geolocation Sensors Breaking CORS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

I have an application that is extracting lat/lng from the geolocation api and and doing some reverse geocoding against a rest api.

I used to be able to use the Chrome sensor overrides in developer tools to test various locations.  However, recently the resultant AJAX call has stopped working and I am getting CORS errors even though I know that the rest api has the CORS headers set correctly.  In fact when I set location to "No Override" the call works as normal.

I have setup a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vp1t2hm7/25/) to demonstrate.  The url it access does not have CORS setup (I couldn't find a public echo one that did), but the behaviour can be seen.

Watch the network tab.  When "No Override" is selected chrome tries to do a straight GET request.  When "London" is selected, Chrome sends an OPTIONS request, this request fails whether the rest api is configured for CORS or not.  Obviously, in the fiddle, all these do fail because of the api, but even a correctly configured endpoint fails with the usual header not set error.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    $.get('https://postman-echo.com/get?q=' + lat + ';' + lng, function(res) {
      console.log(res.body);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding more to Sami's response above:

Browser sensor override was being applied for latitude, longitude, Timezone and Locale. Locale override is causing the browser request header for Accept-Language to be set.

```
Accept-Language: mr_IN
```

So alternatively, you could avoid the error by not setting a Locale override assuming you're interested in just location.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug, but yes you are right leaving locale and timezone blank is a workaround for now.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097677#c_ts1593500548

Comment: Thanks, just place blank in Timezone and Locale.

Comment: @MatthewDolman According to the comments on the issue you linked, the proper fix is to use `mr-IN` instead of `mr_IN`, which CORS-whitelists the header. You don't need to leave the locale blank entirely.

Answer (score 4):

When using location overrides the CORS API should allow the header `Accept-Language`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept-Language
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation for this?

Comment: I couldn't find the exact release change for this, but to confirm it check how Chrome sends the `access-control-request-headers: accept-language` on the OPTIONS request headers only when you override the location.

Comment: Since you're only using this for testing I suggest you use an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino) instead of making changes to your API.

Comment: Thanks, yes I noticed the new header after you pointed it out.  I'm just confused as to why it was changed.  Unfortunately, I won't be the only one testing - I imagine leads will also want to be able to test various locations and so updating the api is going to be the best solution.